# IdentityServer ASP.net CORE MVC ValidAudiences and Role is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4, roles

I have a .net core MVC application, below are my queries

TargetFramework --> "net5.0"

IdentityModel Version--> "5.1.0"

Q1) In which I uses ValidAudiences which is not working. If I use ValidAudience token validation is working fine

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();


            //START for the cookie token based authentication
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

            //Log Single Logout
            services.AddTransient<CookieEventHandler>();
            services.AddSingleton<LogoutSessionManager>();

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                    options.Cookie.Name = "mvc31_";

                    options.EventsType = typeof(CookieEventHandler);
                })
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";
                    
                    options.ClientId = "testmvc31";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code";

                    options.SaveTokens = true;

                    options.Scope.Clear();
                    options.Scope.Add("openid");
                    options.Scope.Add("profile");
                    options.Scope.Add("roles");

                    //adding api1 scope to access api
                    options.Scope.Add("api1");
                    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;

                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        //NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                        RoleClaimType = "role",
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidAudience = "testmvc31", //"testResource",
                        //ValidAudiences = new[] { "testResource1" }, //not working
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                    };
                });
            //END for the cookie token based authentication


        }
```

ValidAudiences suppose to work. Do you have any idea why its not working?

Q2) In Token validation I mentioned that Role is attached to the claims name "role", In access_token I case see the role claims value, But I can not see role claim in User.Claims.ToList() and User.IsInRole("admin") is false ?

```
options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            NameClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Name,
                            RoleClaimType = JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                            ValidateIssuer = true,
                            ValidAudience = "testResource1"
                            //ValidAudiences = new[] { "testResource1" },
                            ValidateAudience = true,
                        };
```

**Access_token**

eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIwMUY0QzVCMzRFNzA3QzhDOTBGNEFFMDgyMkNDRDMxNEZENjlFMzBSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsIng1dCI6IklCOU1XelRuQjhqSkQwcmdnaXpOTVVfV25qQSJ9.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.dA4JOxeWd0cGlzr5BSANNL3ZZATzxchgFwLivQVH4rbyfPr6LRIvep6-NjrNEOL_YvJVCDIEU7TBC0-9qBZVL6OgmjDZBZ5dapNhD8ZZP39bUnfqXLJqRAQgR3yeIlB60EQ3vDEnLen1HZuZJCDoqzXr-sANp75IEOLYPxfDFE5SCljex_zX9AQ1dzAUF4k60N3nbJWwn1aqOM3TdKBG85O_QDWZ-FCg5-7FI55HyrJaF4Ojb6qrFf6WdumWnz6_8sT4r9734X2QftRFeFkId36shUJpxqC-zpf5PJYjgg_rhMZ68vFuWONzKFSbXiYhqoMzCa4JzZItF_9bonXELQ

**Id_token**
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjIwMUY0QzVCMzRFNzA3QzhDOTBGNEFFMDgyMkNDRDMxNEZENjlFMzBSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsIng1dCI6IklCOU1XelRuQjhqSkQwcmdnaXpOTVVfV25qQSJ9.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.KAqpxfctknB5DV8_leOekZajdgYOJ_sLsa12Hx1-qmOS8hLfN0RwpE3MCGyAiKhSEEPwGPXbbAglZnZKDKbH48RwsA-Zvu3Z8qO3_UCgG6U_ghTW3FSHWV2BJMpM_-OCvqq6pwx65Wh_9-u9xRq3F5r6SbgAyEwzjUE925UOMrWgnyWQAVCuVZ-7W2nO3pkLhf5NW0ItUcF5I6TJn54wgcga-JP1rNh2gIIMT4N9ijfcdbbLVrX6wFqKlXEUWOzGW9m8A8oCZ5ZvbJ_iy3mNT-H3DjMO6K-FP2hwNeU7X3nhdvdrVM6_CyvfLQr9bHQVQB9Aj42DAFOQCfR4V2NtNQ

Any idea about this two issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ValidAudiences** in your API must match the **aud** claim in the access token.

You need to use for example:

```
ValidAudience = "testAPI"
```

For the role issue, can you paste a compelte sample access token?

Usually, you need to tell AddJwtBearer the name of your role claim, using:

```
 opt.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "role";
 opt.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
```

Similar to what you have done, so that should work.

Are you sure your role claim in the token is role, not roles?

The access token is not meant to be consumed or inspected by the client application, its only to be consumed by the API. The ID-token is used to create the "user" in the client ASP.NET Core application.

To get user claims into it, its just a matter to add them as a userclaims, like:

```
new IdentityResource(name: "employee", userClaims: new string[] { "role", "employeetype", "IsCeo" })
```

Don't worry if you don't see the role in the IDToken,it will otherwise be retrieved from the UserInfo in a separate requests.

You control this using this flag in the Client definition:

```
// When requesting both an id token and access token, should the user claims always
// be added to the id token instead of requiring the client to use the UserInfo endpoint.
// Defaults to false.
AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = false,
```

In AddOpenIDConnect you also have this flag:

```
options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
```

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://%20https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I have modified the question with access token and the source code I used

Comment: can yo post a sample id-token? the Client will look for the audience in the id-token, not the access token.

Comment: Sorry I confuse with audiences in API configuration Got your point. I have added Id_token.Since I don't have "role" in Id_token it is not able to get the role. Is there any way other than "Always Include User Claims In IdToken" to include certain claim with Id_token?

Comment: updated my answer. feel free to accept the answer if it solves your problem

Comment: I define this way only but role is not found with id_token.  From MVC application I have added scope roles which has the userclaim role but I can not see this in Id_token, any idea

Comment: As I said before, the role claim does not need to be part of the id-token, if it is instead retrieved from the UserInfo endpoint. You can verify this using tools like Fiddler.   Or you set AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken to true, then the claims are added to the id-token if the scope that the claim belongs to is inclueded.... you can always make a request to the userinfo endpoint to see what is available about the user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233270/discussion-between-leo-and-tore-nestenius).